# How can I correctly use this relative pronoun?

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

- *I work with families with many children* ***who*** *have financial problems*

here, **who** actually refers to *children*, not *families*.

How can I re-write this sentence to make it refer to *families*?

Comment: I work with families who have financial problems, partially due to their many children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the phrase : "with many children" parenthetically :

> *"I work with families, with many children, who have financial problems."*

The noun "family" (like class, committee) is a thing though it is made up of people. So your sentence should read

> *"I work with families, with many children, that have financial problems."*

Even if one argues that the noun “family” implies people, “that” is an appropriate relative pronoun, since it can be used for both people and things.